# How can I define a 5x3 array of strings in python?

Tags: python

How can I define a 5x3 array of strings in python?

I want to save the following data in an array of strings:

```
Name    Surname Grade
Steve   Black   10
Jane    Red     10
Peter   Green   0
Kelly   Pink    7
```

I am coming from C/C++ and in this programming language it would look like this:

```
matrix[5][3];

matrix[0][0] = "Name";
matrix[0][1] = "Surname";
matrix[0][2] = "Grade";

matrix[1][0] = "Steve";
matrix[1][1] = "Black";
matrix[1][2] = "10";

...
...
...

matrix[4][0] = "Kelly";
matrix[4][1] = "Pink";
matrix[4][2] = "7";
```

Is there a way in python to create such table?

In case you know what kind of data type that is in python and how it work, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you should read the official Python tutorial first, it will spare you from many more questions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: When looking at C++, I would strongly suggest **against** such a matrix. In order to store such information, I would have created a struct which contains the relevant information, and just make a `std::vector` of this struct. It can be done in python by using a class, or just creating a tuple of the arguments (although - if you can name it, you should create a class for it!).

Comment: @Kerek I agree with you, the question is asked for learning purposes only.

Answer (score 4):

Put it in a nested list

```
a = [["Steve", "Black", 10], ["Jane", "Red", 10], ["Peter", "Green", 0], ["Kelly", "Pink", 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) for this. 
    import numpy as np

```
matrix_data = np.array([["Name", "Surname", "Grade"],
                    ["Steve", "Black", "10"],
                    ["Jane", "Red", "10"],
                    ["Peter", "Green", "0"],
                    ["Kelly", "Pink", "7"]])
```

You can access elements of the array created using the line of code below,

**Code:**

```
print(matrix_data[0][2])
```

**Output:**

```
Grade
```

Using numpy is specifically useful when trying to obtain subsets of this matrix like shown below,

**Code:**

```
matrix_data[:,2]
```

**Output:**

```
['Grade' '10' '10' '0' '7']
```

Comment: This code works exactly the same if you omit `np.array`. NumPy is not needed here at all.

Comment: `matrix_data[:,2]` could your suggestion bring a value to this code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the three lists defined as

```
firstnames = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
lastnames = ["w", "x", "y", "z"]
grades = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then you could `zip` the lists, and use list comprehension as

```
merged = [[e1, e2, e3] for (e1, e2, e3) in zip(firstnames, lastnames, grades)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a 2-d list in python and loop through it filling the required values in following manner -

```
lst = []        #currently a 1-d list but you can insert lists into it and make it a 2-d list.
#just for demo...you can loop instead to fill all the values
new_row = []
new_row.append("Steve")
new_row.append("Black")
new_row.append(10)
lst.append(new_row)
print(lst)     #this would print a 2-d list - [["Steve","Black",10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
data = \
'''
Name    Surname Grade
Steve   Black   10
Jane    Red     10
Peter   Green   0
Kelly   Pink    7
'''

matrix = [line.split() for line in data.strip().split('\n')]
print(matrix)
```

Answer (score -3):

Python doesn't have multidimensional arrays, but you can achieve a similar affect by nesting lists. [Python Arrays - w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp)